# How to learn a treshold value for image representations?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, information-retrieval

I implemented a Content Based Image Retrieval system, which encode images into [VLAD codes](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOzfyf7tPSAhVBC2MKHY2DDR4QFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vlfeat.org%2Fapi%2Fvlad.html&usg=AFQjCNFL5grp0dLmHYMN5GzIgokuhnMZag&sig2=UAxzj_VGtxkSB-lOQqk2bg). In few words, an image is a vector in thousands of dimensions, and the similarity between two images is measured as the L2 distance between the two correspondent VLAD vectors. In practice, we return as result the top-k minimum distances between the query code and all the dataset codes.

Now, I'm testing this system on the [Oxford Building Dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/oxbuildings/), which is a popular dataset for testing your CBIR system: there are 55 query images, and we compute the Mean Average Precision to evaluate your approach.

Given a query image, the set of true positives is defined as the union between "good" and "ok" images. These sets were manually created by the dataset authors, for more info read the original paper (ref in the link above).

So, supposing perfect VLAD codes, `topk[0]` is the most similar image between the dataset images, and it has the smallest L2 distance w.r.t. the query code. **Notice that this is going to be used for object recognition applications**, so given the query image we want to return the most similar image (and not the top-k values), so this threshold should be computed considering only the top-1 distances.

**What I want to do** is to learn a `treshold` value s.t. if `topk[0]<treshold` we can safely assume that this is a related image.

Machine learning isn't really my field, but this what came to my mind to learn this value: we compute the average of `topk[0]` of all images where `topk[0]` image is a true positive, while we don't consider false positives (they would pollute this threshold vaue). I realize that this is a very naive solution, but nothing better came to my mind.

For my implementation, I noticed that `top[0]` is usually between `1.0*` and `1.3*` for good matches, while usually very "distant" images have `>1.5*`

Comment: Why do you need machine learning to determine the threshold? Can't you just save the results of your tested images (like: expectedValue = "equal/unequal", threshold) then write a loop, iterate over all images for different thresholds and check how many of them are correct for every threshold? Then take the best.

Comment: @FlorianH Thanks for your comment. Could you please explain better what do you mean by the expectedValue=equal/unequal ?

Comment: For every comparisation of two pictures you save two things. First: what you expected (wether they are related oder not related). So you label them by hand. Second: the topk[0] you got for the comparisation. Then you can make a loop, lets say (for double threshold = 0.01; threshold < 10; threshold+=0.01). Inside that loop you check how many comparisations are correct, how many incorrect. Take the threshold where you got most correct.

Comment: @FlorianH So what you suggest is: (1) For each query *q_i* compute the distance *d_i(q_i,img_i)*, where *img_i* is the closest image in the dataset, so we will obtain the set of distances *d_1(q_1, img_1), ... d_n(q_n,img_n)* (2) given a threshold *t*, add *img_i* to the set of matched images if * d(q_i,img_i) <=  t * , obtaining the set of matched images *M* (3) See how many images in *M* are true positives *MP* (so *MP* is a subset of *M*) and compute the ratio *ratio=MP/M* (4) repeat (2)-(3) changing *t* in order to maxize *ratio*. Did I summarized your approach correctly?

Comment: Yes that sums it up. You can also check the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall to find a evaluation metrik that fits your purpose. Devide (mp/p) seems to make not so much sense. If you just stupidly classify all querries positive you reach the maximum (for mp/p), which is for sure not what you want. In other words you have somehow to look at least at your false positives.

Comment: So what I was considering was recall (since p = mp + false negatives). So do you suggest to consider also precision, and choose the threshold obtained by the maximum in the precision/recall curve?

Comment: My bad, is misread your last comment and thought P are all images. so recall would be a possibility. What you take in the end depends on what you want. I recommend to read https://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/de/Members/salfner/publications/salfner10survey.pdf . On page seven they start to explain evaluation metrics very well, the advandages of every single one. So read those 5 pages and decide what fits your purpuse.

Comment: @FlorianH I was not considering the ROC curve, which could be very useful in this context, since I really care about maxizing true positives and minimizing false negatvies. In addition, ROC curve is used specifically for (from wikipedia) "illustrates the performance of a binary classifier system as its discrimination threshold is varied". What do you think?

Comment: ROC courve might be the best thing to use. It works unlike e.g. accuracy also for really unbalanced datasets

Answer (score 0):

In general I would recommend looking into some other ways of quantifying the similarity of images with important properties, such as scale-invariant detection, robustness to changes in lighting and so on. If you just want a threshold value for your L2-norm, there are several ways of going about it. What value is "best" very much depends on what you want. If you value minimizing false positives, that should be your cost-function, if you value avoiding false negatives than you should optimize for that... you could also try to optimize both at the same time where you give both therms a weight in your cost function. One approach I can think of is:

1. only take half your data-set
2. choose a threshold (in the middle of the range you expect to be plausible)
3. classify your data with this threshold and count false positives, false negatives, true positives and true negatives and assess your quality
4. consider these cases:

   - if the result is satisfying, stick with it for now
   - if you have too many false positives make your threshold more strict (cut the unexplored interval on the more strict side in half)
   - if you have too many false negatives make your threshold less strict (cut the unexplored interval on the less strict side in half)
5. repete until you are satisfied / have the optimal balance.
6. predict the half you did not take to find your threshold and validate your result.

Just one option to think of but maybe you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. We are going to use this for object recognition (given a query image, return the most similar image representing the same subject), so we want to minimize false positives, there are no false negatives. How do you suggest to proceed in such a scenario?

Comment: Another question: you consider only half of the dataset because the other half will be used to evaluate if the chosen threshold is good or not, right?

Comment: @justHelloWorld yes exactly. If you are satisfied with the evaluation you can then repeat this with the entire data-set. The approach I suggested is a simple bisection search for the "right" value. the important thing in step 4 is to estimate if your threshold is too high or too low. The problem with not considering false negatives is that the way to never have any false positives is to never detect any image as positive... so you could use something like "at least 2 detected and at most x false positives"

Comment: if you really want to get into object recognition, I suggest you read stuff such as this http://www.vision.caltech.edu/CNS179/papers/Lades93.pdf and of course the more current stuff in the field (mostly layered classifier neural nets... some such algorithms have implementations in scipy)

Comment: "The problem with not considering false negatives is that the way to never have any false positives is to never detect any image as positive... so you could use something like "at least 2 detected and at most x false positives"" what do you mean here? I'm sorry for not understanding this :)

Comment: I've seen that in the paper that you linked there is a section about defining a threshold. Did you linked it for that reason? As I said in my question, we have already a solid image representation (VLAD), even if not so good as the ones given by CNNs (but VLAD is faster and we really care about performances here).

Comment: @justHelloWorld no problem... No I did not link the paper for that reason (just in general I think its interesting). If you have a representation you like you can stick with it. The thing i was talking about before: If you do not care about not recognizing the "right" images but you do care about recognizing the "wrong" ones, I can satisfy that without any computer... I will just always tell you "No sorry wrong image". I will not once have a false positive, because I will never have any positive...

Comment: As I was saying in question's comments, what about deciding the threshold according to the ROC curve? The ROC curve is used especially in binary classifiers (which is something similar to this) to decide good threshold values. What we want to maximize is TP/FP (maximize the number of true positives and minimize false positives) and so I could take the maximum of this w.r.t the chosen threshold. What do you think? Oh, and btw thanks so much, it's not common to see someone in stackoverflow so available to help :)

Comment: @justHelloWorld sounds good to me... TP/FP is in my opinion a good cost-function to optimize and ROC curve analysis seams reasonable to me... (but of course I can't guarantee that it will work).